# Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC

Tags: android, garbage-collection

I am using Kotlin Fuel framework to make REST API calls. Actually everything was working fine as far as when the api has http uri. But as soon as when the uris are made as HTTPs with SSL certificate installation, I could not download image from amazon server. I get the following error and its blocking the UI. Does anyone have a clue on how to fix this issue?

```
11-11 12:26:34.865 5060-5071/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 39770(1365KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(136KB) LOS objects, 39% free, 4MB/7MB, paused 10ms total 10ms
11-11 12:26:43.525 5060-5071/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 111790(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 25% free, 7MB/9MB, paused 10ms total 10ms
11-11 12:26:44.885 5060-5071/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 106842(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 7MB/9MB, paused 10ms total 10ms
11-11 12:26:54.995 5060-5071/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 59898(1545KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 10% free, 8MB/9MB, paused 10ms total 20ms
11-11 12:27:00.265 5060-5071/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 114185(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 28% free, 7MB/9MB, paused 10ms total 10ms
11-11 12:27:01.935 5060-5071/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 108091(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 26% free, 7MB/9MB, paused 10ms total 10ms
11-11 12:27:02.725 5060-5071/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 146869(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 5MB/9MB, paused 10ms total 10ms
11-11 12:27:10.155 5060-5071/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 146572(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 5MB/9MB, paused 10ms total 10ms
11-11 12:27:30.495 5060-5071/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 128730(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 5MB/8MB, paused 10ms total 10ms
11-11 12:27:35.415 5060-5071/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 127365(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 5MB/9MB, paused 10ms total 10ms
11-11 12:27:55.475 5060-5071/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 109081(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 22% free, 7MB/9MB, paused 10ms total 10ms
11-11 12:27:59.775 5060-5071/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 147790(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 5MB/9MB, paused 10ms total 10ms
11-11 12:28:17.665 5060-5071/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 101333(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 25% free, 6MB/9MB, paused 10ms total 10ms
11-11 12:28:25.535 5060-5071/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 99883(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free, 7MB/9MB, paused 10ms total 10ms
11-11 12:28:28.725 5060-5071/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 135684(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 5MB/9MB, paused 10ms total 10ms
11-11 12:28:31.445 1323-1347/? I/UsageStatsService: User[0] Flushing usage stats to disk
11-11 12:28:38.905 5060-5071/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 93984(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 25% free, 6MB/8MB, paused 10ms total 10ms
11-11 12:28:43.375 5060-5071/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 98648(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 26% free, 6MB/9MB, paused 10ms total 10ms
11-11 12:28:55.955 5060-5071/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 104358(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 5MB/8MB, paused 10ms total 10ms
11-11 12:29:00.305 5060-5071/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 61484(1533KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 6MB/8MB, paused 10ms total 10ms
11-11 12:29:09.045 5060-5071/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 148335(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 6MB/10MB, paused 10ms total 10ms
11-11 12:29:15.585 5060-5071/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 67502(1690KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 14% free, 7MB/8MB, paused 10ms total 10ms
11-11 12:29:25.865 5060-5071/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 68175(1710KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 15% free, 7MB/9MB, paused 10ms total 10ms
11-11 12:29:56.835 5060-5071/? W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10ms
11-11 12:29:56.875 5060-5071/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 115432(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free, 7MB/10MB, paused 10ms total 10ms
```

Comment: This is the JSON Parsing issue. Please make sure you are parsing the response JSON correctly. Thanks.

Comment: hey i got the same issue,do u have any solutions?

Comment: I second @User. It's a json decode issue. Check your storage as well, if you're using any.